# extension for UITextfield keyboard appearance

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield

in my app, I will add different themes, but for now, I want to write an extension that can handle keyboard appearance from extension. 
for the first step, I just want to have control of its appearance, so I set that it should be `.dark` but it's not working. could you tell me where is the problem in this simple extension?
I just want it to change the keyboard appearance automatically without doing anything else

```
extension UITextView {


  var keyboardApperance: UIKeyboardAppearance? {
    get {
        return self.keyboardAppearance
    }
    set {
         self.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you using this?

Comment: I just want it to change the keyboard appearance automatically without doing anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating just an extension doesn't change your `UITextView` properties.

You can create your own custom `UITextView` and use it instead of UITextView.

Don't forget to set your class if you are using storyboard or xib.

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomDarkTextView: UITextView {

    public override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        setup()
    }

    public convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(frame: frame, textContainer: nil)
        setup()
    }

    public convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero, textContainer: nil)
        setup()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

trying using functions like this

```
extension UITextView {
    func setKeyboardToDark() {
        self.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    }

    func setKeyboardToLight() {
        self.keyboardAppearance = .light
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately it is not working

Comment: @JOnney Are you actually calling `someTextfield.setKeyboardToDark()` ?

Comment: if `someTextField` is of type `UITextView`, then the answer to your question ^^^ is yes

Answer (score 0):

```
  extension UITextView {
            func setDarkKeyboard() {
            self.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
           }

            func setLightKeyboard() {
            self.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.light
          }
     }
```